# Generating different checksum second time using AES algorithm in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, aes, checksum

I am trying to generate encrypted value which should be different every second time.My payload is something like this
{
"name":"abc",
"password":"23"
}
I want different encrypted value every second time what I can do to achieve this whenever I hit my API

Answer (score 0):

Use an initialization vector. Here's an example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-encryption-iv